# FirebaseInstanceId Token retrieval failed SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an android app, it uses Firebase Authentication, Database and Storage. It was all working fine until this error message started to show up in logcat. (I did not tamper with any configs at firebase console)

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

this error message shows even when I have commented on all firebase-related code.
 Therefore I'm unable to proceed with authentication and other firebase-related stuff.
Yes, I'm connected to the internet and also have gotten a new Google-Services.json file from Firebase Console but it has made no difference at all.

Comment: Do you have play services enabled?

Comment: yes both Google play services and Google play store are enabled in my device. Any idea about what other issue could be?
I've tried the same code on an android emulator and it worked. I don't know how my physical device got this problem, it worked fine before this.

Comment: so, I was able to resolve it finally! It turns out that Google play services were enabled, but they were restricted over Cellular Data.
To solve it, I did the following:
App Data Usage -> Google Services -> Turn Off the "Restrict Cellular Data Access" option

Comment: Restart your phone....worked for me ..

Comment: Hey 
I am getting the same issue but didn't solved it by--> Turn Off the "Restrict Cellular Data Access" option .
Any help will appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Enabling only one type of network connection (wifi or lte) worked for me.

Comment: Restarted phone.. worked for me..

Answer (score 101):

"Cold Boot Now" Device in AVD Manager worked for me.

Edit:
After updating emulators and than doing the cold boot it helped. – parohy Apr 5 at 9:22

Comment: After updating emulators and than doing the cold boot it helped.

Comment: Cold boot did it for me. Thanks

Comment: That was it all along!? Is there a specific reason this would fix the issue? Maybe having different applicationIdSuffixes with each flavor or something?

Comment: This tip work for me too. Working with Flutter with an emulated devide on Android Studio.

Comment: I went to the AVD Manager, click on device and then show advanced settings and finally i switched to "Cold Boot Now", then save and my issue was gone, thansk!

Comment: "Cold Boot" worked also for me; thx for the hint

Comment: in my case after "Cold boot", for only first time, getting this error, if i just reopen the app then issue is not there, so should i expect that this error will not come in real devices??

Answer (score 29):

Stop emulator device and open AVD Manager Panel, edit device configuration.
In device configuration panel "Show Advanced Settings" in "Emulated Performance" section select "**Cold boot**" option as *Boot Option* then click Finish, it should be worked.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

I also faced with this issue. As I can see it can happen for many reasons.

Finally I figured out that my problem was that the current latest Facebook Android SDK version (v4.36.0) has a bug. Everything works fine if I set it back to v4.35.0. Maybe this info can help someone in the future.

You can find here the releases: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/releases

Comment: Using com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0 caused white blank screen on loading of mine application. Changed to 4.35.0, fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! You just saved me!

Comment: I downgraded to v4.35.0 of FacebookSDK and that fixed the problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was having the same issue in Android Q - API 29, and this fixed it. Thanks

Comment: It's glad to hear that! You can also try to upgrade to the latest one since it was already fixed in the upcoming versions.

Answer (score 9):

you need to update the emulator to the latest version that includes Google Play services

Answer (score 7):

For future readers:

Found this error when I set device ***date different than current***
and open. My application logs start printing similar log.
Solution: restart your device and it will start working fine.

Answer (score 5):

I changed my emulator and now it is working correctly without any error.

Answer (score 5):

Check that Google play services are enabled

if it still shows error Now try these steps

Step 1 - Stop emulator device

Step 2 - open AVD Manager Panel, edit device configuration. In device configuration panel "Show Advanced Settings" in "Emulated 
 Performance" section select "Cold boot" option as Boot Option then click Finish, it should be worked.

If this does not work try to work on different Emulator

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was facing an Internet connectivity Issue. Make sure your Internet Connection is Strong enough to Generate FcmToken.

Comment: Me too. Actually, I had weak WIFI and thought it would keep the connection stable. But this error kept coming. Apparently, that is the real issue. Thank you. Now I use mobile connection for this. I would never use that weak WIFI again.

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Studio 2022** menu:

1. Tools
2. Android
3. **Android Device Manager**
4. Select device and click Edit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Root cause: You miss google services in your device.
So if you use emulator then apply "Cold boot" mode in advanced setting,
if you use real device please change another
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was a connection issue with my emulator.  I was unable to load websites outside of my company's VPN. Probably worth confirming that you can do that (load up yahoo or stackoverflow on the device's browser) if you're having this issue.  Once I figured out my emulator's connection issues, I was able to get the token.

Answer (score 0):

wipe android emulator data and than run emulator its work for me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is so simple and You have to cold-boot your android emulator